# Having trouble using java.arraycopy. (ArrayIndexOutofBounds)

Tags: java, exception, arrays

I am trying to read a csv file and copy it's data into an array. I can't seem to get it to work this way and I'm not sure why.

```
String[] row = new String[0];
ArrayList<String[]> csv = new ArrayList<>();

String parser = "SPImages";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C://data.csv"));
String[] nextLine;


while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null){
    System.arraycopy(nextLine, 0, row, 0, nextLine.length);
}
```

Comment: Well how large is `row`? In fact, what's its type?

Comment: I updated my question with the code where I create `row`

Comment: `row` must have at least the size of the `nextLine.length`!

Comment: @MrSmith42 Ignore that part. It was a comment for something else I was trying to do. I just forgot to delete it. I will now.

Comment: @Aaron Lemon: but even when `row` is big enough for the arraycopy, you will overwrite the content with each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the destination array (in this case "row") is not as big as the source array (in this case "nextLine").  Arrays, unlike Lists, don't auto-resize.

Comment: So I should create `row` after finding the size of `nextLine`, huh?

Comment: Exactly, your row must be of proper size, as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Yes, now that the source code has been updated to include the declaration of row, this is the problem.  You will need to create "row" anew each time in the loop, or else you will just be copying over your data each time.

Comment: @Aaron Lemon: or better define it big enough from the beginning.

Comment: I think he has to create a new instance of row each time through the loop, right?  Assuming "row" will be appended to the "csv" variable.  If there's just one declaration of "row", that same memory will be overwritten with each line.

Comment: Yes, you and MrSmith are correct on that. Thank you for the help.